# Drawbacks of Robotlegs 2 compared with PureMVC

Tags: actionscript-3, robotlegs, puremvc

I want to understand what kind of drawbacks has Robotlegs 2 compared with PureMVC. Seems it is more elegant, more convenient and as much powerful as PureMVC. What is the reason PureMVC should live except the legacy codebase? Would it be time in nearest future that PureMVC will die as far as Robotlegs is living. I think this question may be answered by a person who knows both frameworks very well in practice.

Answer (score 2):

PureMVC is generally much faster than RobotLegs in terms of performance. This is because the dependency injection RobotLegs relies on is quite slow.

However, most will agree that the cleaner, more intuitive API of RobotLegs more than makes up for this.

Comment: So if we don't have performance bottlenecks, then Robotlegs is the right choice? Is there any other reason to chose PureMVC?

Comment: The only other strong reason that comes to mind would be that there are ports of PureMVC to various different languages, which could potentially make porting apps easier.

Comment: Robotlegs also has ports. And on the other hand PureMVC should be slow too when you ask facade to give you a proxy or so.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the only person who can make the decision as to which of the two frameworks is best for you and your project is you.

That said, I think I can still offer you some advice to help you with your decision. I'll assume that lack of dependency injection is not a deal-breaker for you since, if it was, you would already have chosen to go with RobotLegs (though it may be worth considering whether you plan to do any unit testing now or in the future, in which case RobotLegs is probably the [better choice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140992/is-dependency-injection-essential-for-unit-testing)).

Spend some time looking at them both and go with the one which feels right for you. They're both great frameworks and, if used correctly, will both help you to write consistent, modular, maintainable, and reusable code. If you decide along the way that you prefer the other framework, simply make the switch. If you've followed the philosophy of the framework you started with, it should be reasonably trivial to port your domain specific code to the other framework.